# Another word for "From the very beginning"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, sentence-patterns

How the rephrase "From the very beginning" in a sentence in a more direct way?

For example, the sentence is

> From the very beginning of the notion normed linear spaces, a considerable effort has been made to carry forward various concepts of Euclidean Geometry to the framework of normed linear spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Especially since you're talking about a concept, I'd recommend: "Since the conception of normed linear spaces...", or "Since the first conception of normed linear spaces...", with "first" added for emphasis. "Since the invention of..." or "Since the discovery of..." might also satisfy.

To emphasize that Euclidean considerations are fundamental to normed linear spaces, I might suggest focusing on the whole timeline instead of simply the beginning: "Throughout the whole history of normed linear spaces, considerable effort has been made to integrate various concepts of Euclidean Geometry."

Answer (score 1):

Another word/phrase that is commonly used is *from the get-go*.

> **from the get-go**
>
> from the very beginning
>
> - She didn't like me *from the get-go*.
> - They were involved in the project *from the get-go*.
>
> [[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/from%20the%20get-go)]

Answer (score 0):

"The beginning of the notion" is not idiomatic; "From the beginning in the developing of the notion of normed linear spaces" would be. A one-word term is the adverb "*outright*".

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/outright_2)) **3.**  not gradually; immediately
> ♦ Most of the crash victims were killed outright.
> ♦ We had saved enough money to buy the house outright.

*Here is a possible rephrasing.*

- In the developing of the notion of  normed linear spaces, a considerable effort has been made *outright* to carry forward various concepts of Euclidean Geometry to the framework of this new algebraic structure.

Comment: In the theme of “out-“ I think ***outset*** fits better with OP’s intent.  *From the outset*…

Comment: @Jim this is good too , but what has been asked is _one_ word meaning "_from the very beginning_", and you'd still have to say "from the _very_ outset".

Comment: But outright does not mean “from the very beginning” in any sense that I know of.

Comment: @Jim It means "immediately" , "at once" (in the developing) (https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/immediately_1?q=immediately) ( https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/outright_2) , therefore at the beginning (wouldn't you think?).